# environment variables are undefined

Tags: node.js, .env

Есть файл .env, содержащий переменные вида: 
REACT_APP_EMAIL = email
REACT_APP_PASS = password

При вызове этих переменных, они undefined.

Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызываю переменные в файле server.js (при этом использую dotenv)

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/contacts', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(process.env)
    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const htmlEmail = `
        <h3>Contact details</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `;
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            secure: true,
            requireTLS: true,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL,
                pass: process.env.REACT_APP_PASS
            }
        })



        transporter.verify(function(error, success) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            } else {
              console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
            }
          });
        let mailOptions = {
            from: '',
            to: 'serzhan.helen@gmail.com',
            subject: 'New message',
            text: req.body.message,
            html: htmlEmail
        }
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }


            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.message)
            // console.log('Message URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
        })
    })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Serve any static files
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

    // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
    });
  }

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);

})
```

При этом, если посмотреть в консоли в файле index.js(который в папке src), то переменные отображаются с нужным значением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все правильно вы указали. попробуйте  следующее: закомментите весь свой код и выполните этот:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('dotenv').config();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send(process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`)
})
```